# Can I use 'can' for making suggestions?

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal, can-modal

All of the grammar books I've read say I have to use 'could' for making suggestions, but none of them say so about 'can'. My question is: **Is it valid to use 'can' for making suggestions?** For example:

*We can take the train*

Instead of *We could take the train*

Both sound correct (for me), the way I see it is that the variant with 'could' sound more *polite* than the variant with 'can'. The first variant sounds even more natural (for me again) when I add another clause:

*We can take the train if you want to*

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using "can" is a common way of making a suggestion, or implying one by giving a possible choice. It's very casual/friendly/informal.

Both can be used to make a suggestion. One difference is that "*We **can** take the train*" can also be used to *assert* what we're going to do, rather than merely making a suggestion. "*We **could** take the train*" cannot be used in this way, so where there's ambiguity, "could" is clearer that it's a suggestion, not an assertion.

Comment: When making a suggestion: If so what is the difference between: “We can take the train” & “We could take the train”

Comment: @LEHANH I've added a paragraph to my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Shall we** [take the train? or whatever] is often used for suggestions.

Although you can use "Can" as in "Can we take the train?", that is really more about the possibility of taking the train as opposed to, say, driving to a place.

Comment: “Could we take the train?” is  the same ?

Comment: @LEHANH Could is "more conditional" than can.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t get the meaning of “more conditional “

Comment: @LEHANH If I can go by car, I will go by car. If I could go by car, I would go by car.